# VirtualBox on Windows 10 - Linux kernel, issues with Intel Pentium g4400 gpu drivers

Tags: drivers, system-installation, graphics, xorg, intel

I tried to install both Debian and Ubuntu last versions as virtual machines, but I couldn't use neither because of an issue with my Intel Pentium g4400. The fact is that Debian gives a white error screen with something like *Something has gone wrong* etc, while Ubuntu apparently loads the GUI but has several bugs. Only terminal mode worked properly.

Here are two screenshots from my BIOS about Intel VT-x technology.

[Cpu support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heJyB.png)

[Actual cpu configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2ZgB.png)

**EDIT :** I found that the problem is the current kernel version. I instead installed OpenMandriva LX 3 that uses 4.6.5 kernel, and I have no problems.
For who whants to try this OS: the only thing is that it's a bit too customized (e.g. I wasn't able to use the official VIM version).

Comment: Errmmm... Ubuntu *is* Debian.

Comment: @AndroidDev: Not true, Ubuntu is based on Debian. UrbiJr: What versions of Debian and Ubuntu? Have you tried the somewhat outdated Ubuntu 15.10?

Comment: @wb9688 The latest, Debian 8.6 and Ubuntu 16.10. I didn't try any other. I'll try with the 15.10 then

Comment: @UrbiJr If you're installing them as virtual machines then, depending on the virtualization software/method, the host CPU/GPU may not matter at all, i.e., if it's working in the host OS and virtualization support has been enabled at UEFI, everything should just work. I suggest you update your question with the missing information: Host OS and virtualization software. PS - Do NOT use unsupported releases. The question above was not a suggestion..

Comment: @UrbiJr I run several VMs, including Windows 10 and Linux Deepin (Debian based), in an Ubuntu 16.04 host running on an older and weaker Intel Pentium.

Comment: @CelticWarrior what's the problem then? However, I used VirtualBox

Comment: @UrbiJr Again, please edit your question, not just comment. Edit it so it mentions both Virtualbox and the **host OS**. Also please check and enable **VT-x** if not already enabled at UEFI and if it was already please do mention it in your edit. I don't know what the problem is but I or someone else might if all the relevant information is provided.

Comment: @UrbiJr Still waiting for the updated question... Preferably with all the relevant informations added, the off-side comments removed and no bold...

Comment: @UrbiJr I meant the off-side comments in the question itself. And also the unneeded bold (which you already did). And add what really matters like whether or not VT-x is enabled.

Comment: @CelticWarrior just updated the question and added two screenshots. Waiting for your instructions!

Comment: @CelticWarrior still waiting..